# Jenkins withDockerRegistry for image out of stage failing

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, docker-registry

I have a problem when I build the image in one stage, and I try to push to registry in another stage:

This code works ok:

```
    stage('Push Image to registry') {
      steps{
        script{
          withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: 'gcr:xxxx', url: 'http://eu.gcr.io/xxxxx/') {
            def dockerImageNginx = docker.build registrynginx + ":$BUILD_NUMBER", "-f dockerfilenginx ." 
            dockerImageNginx.push()
          }
        }
      }
```

But when I try to build the Image in one stage, and push, in another stage, like this:
(This is because I use the Image to run several test, and when the test is passed, I push the image, not before)

```
    stage('Building image NGINX') {
      steps{
        script {
          def dockerImageNginx = docker.build registrynginx + ":$BUILD_NUMBER", "-f dockerfilenginx ."  
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Push Image to registry') {
      steps{
        script{
          withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: 'gcr:xxxxx', url: 'http://eu.gcr.io/xxxx/') {
            dockerImageNginx.push()
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This give me this error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: dockerImageNginx for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:291)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:295)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:61)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor832.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How I can solve this error? 
maybe its a problem that var dockerimagenginx is not global?
Also, I can push the image with the command docker push, but I think this is more clean.

Comment: I know I can do a sh " docker push [image]" but I'm asking because I thinks this method is more clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to make your variable global, you can define it on top of your Jenkinsfile, outside the `pipeline`:

```
def dockerImageNginx
pipeline {
...
stage('Building image NGINX') {
  steps{
    script {
      dockerImageNginx = docker.build registrynginx + ":$BUILD_NUMBER", "-f dockerfilenginx ."  
    }
  }
}
stage('Push Image to registry') {
  steps{
    script{
      withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: 'gcr:xxxxx', url: 'http://eu.gcr.io/xxxx/') {
        dockerImageNginx.push()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ruben then please accept this answer. That says thank you, other people see that the question is solved, and you get 2 reputation points.

Comment: how can validate this answer? 
In previus questions I have a button on the top of the page to validate the question

Comment: normally you should see a big checkmark next to my answer, just under the up- and downvote buttons.